# Add row with dependent dropdown

Tags: php, ajax

I need help from you. In the page i have one div with select field.Below it I have table with some fields (one is dropdown, dependent of the first) and button to add rows.
First select box populate the select box in the table and the field next to it with a script and this works fine till there is one row. If i add new row the dropdown is losing it's connection with the first dropdown. I suppose the problem is with the id but have no idea how to solve this. Any directions are appreciated.

This is the first dropdown:

```
<div><select name="line" id="line">
                            <option value="">
                                Choose line
                            </option>
                            <?php foreach ($lines as $line) {
                            ?>
                                <option value="<?= $line['cont_line_id'] ?>">
                                    <?= $line['line'] ?>
                                </option>

                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addLine" style="margin-right:15px">
                            Добави
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

Table html code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">


                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">

                        <tr>
                            <th>BL/SWB</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Container</th>
                            <th>+</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            
                        </tr>

                        <div id="dynamic_field">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <tr>
                                    <td contenteditable="true" class="b_l" name="b_l[]" style="width: 250px; text-align:center">
                                </td>
                                    <td style="width:100px;">
                                        <div><input type="date" name="date[]" id="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td contenteditable="false" class="container" style="width:150px;">
                                        <div> <select id="tr_means" name="tr_means[]">
                                                <option value="">
                                                    Choose container
                                                </option>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                                                       
                                    <td contenteditable="false" class="ctype" id="cont_type" style="width: 40px;"></td>

                                    
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <button type="button" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">+</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>


                                </tr>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </table>

                    <div align="center">
                        <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="nav-buttons">Save</button>
                    </div>
                                 
                </div>
```

```
//Line Container Numbers

        $(document).on('click', '#line', function() {
            var lineID = $(this).val();
            if (lineID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/multitransport/ajax/line_con.php',
                    data: {
                        'line_id': lineID

                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#tr_means').html(result);


                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#tr_means').html('<option value="">Choose container</option>');
            }
        });

        //Get selected cont type according to number


        $('#tr_means').change(function() {
            //Selected value
            var contID = $(this).val();
            if (contID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/multitransport/ajax/cont_type.php',
                    data: {
                        'cont_id': contID
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#cont_type').html(result);

                    }
                });
            }


        });
```

The corresponding urls' are:
line_con.php

```
include('../includes/db_connect.php');

$line_id=$_POST['line_id'];

if(!empty($line_id)){
$query='SELECT * FROM tbl_containers, tbl_cont_types WHERE line_id=? AND tbl_containers.cont_type=tbl_cont_types.cont_type_id ORDER BY number ASC';
$stmt=$connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$line_id]);

if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
    
    echo "<option >Choose container</option>";
    while($arr=$stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo"<option value='".$arr['cont_id']."'>".$arr['number']."</option><br>";
    }
}
}
```

cont_type.php

```
include('../includes/db_connect.php');

$cont_id=$_POST['cont_id'];

if(!empty($cont_id)){

$arr="";

$query='SELECT type from tbl_containers, tbl_cont_types WHERE cont_id=? AND tbl_containers.cont_type=tbl_cont_types.cont_type_id';
$stmt=$connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$cont_id]);

if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
    
    echo "  ";
  
    while($arr=$stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $arr['type'];
    }
}
}
```

This is the script to append new rows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      
      var count = 0;

      $(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td contenteditable="true" class="b_l" name="b_l[]" style="width: 250px; text-align:center"></td>';
        html += '<td><div><input type="date" name="date[]" id="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"></div></td>';
        html += '<td> <select name="tr_means[]" id="tr_means'+count+'"><option value="">Choose container</option></select></td>'
       
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
```

Comment: you're using #tr_means in a change function but when you add a new one you have #tr_means2 #tr_means3 etc. You need to use classes $(document).on('change', .tr_means', function() {... and you'll have to update the rest of the script to use classes in the other spots as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply #Func Doc. This helps but when new row is added if i have to click again the first dropdown and all the selected values of the table dropdown disappear. It is not keeping the selected value of rows.

Comment: You have to update all the javascript and html to have classes, and also remember that when using jquery something like $(".line") is going to be an array of items. I also suggest you refactor this using vanilla javascript, there is no need for jquery here, and writing the scripts again will help you nail down each step and squash bugs.